# Display Javascript variables in HTML label

Tags: javascript, html, variables, label, show

I have this commercial in a web site.

http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/5157/mv8k.png (Image).

This commercial contain prices' information and those prices are in javascript variables. I want to update the prices automatically when I updated the variables values (The prices are between "Desde" and "Bs." at the red color  font).

The html to display those labels are the following:

```
    <ul style="list-style-type:circle; margin-top:0px;">
      <li><a href="http://printoriente.com/tarjetas-presentacion/">Tarjetas de presentaci&oacute;n</a><label class="printoriente-label"> - Desde </label><label class="printoriente-tp-price"></label><label class="printoriente-label">Bs.</label></li>
      <li><a href="http://printoriente.com/afiches/">Afiches</a><label class="printoriente-label"> - Desde </label><label class="printoriente-label-price"></label><label class="printoriente-label">Bs.</label></li>
      <li><a href="http://printoriente.com/volantes/">Volantes</a><label class="printoriente-label"> - Desde </label><label class="printoriente-label-price"></label><label class="printoriente-label">Bs.</label></li>
      <li><a href="http://printoriente.com/fotos/">Fotos</a><label class="printoriente-label"> - </font>Desde <label class="printoriente-label-price"></label><label class="printoriente-label">Bs.</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p style="padding-left:20px; font-size:12px; margin-top:20px;"> Vis&iacute;tanos y ver&aacute;s lo f&aacute;cil que es dise&ntilde;ar!</p>
</div>

<script>
$.getJSON( "http://api.printoriente.com/price/tarjetas-presentacion", function( data ) {
  console.log(data.refPrice);
});
$.getJSON( "http://api.printoriente.com/price/afiches", function( data ) {
  console.log(data.refPrice);
});
$.getJSON( "http://api.printoriente.com/price/volantes", function( data ) {
  console.log(data.refPrice);
});
$.getJSON( "http://api.printoriente.com/price/Fotos", function( data ) {
  console.log(data.refPrice);
});
</script>
```

The prices are in "data.refPrice" variable. I want to display those variables in the labels only with the class "printoriente-label-price". I investigated something about ".each" and ".find" in javascript, I dont know if it coould be a solution.

I did it with ids but It generates conflicts with the rest of the web site. I have to do It with other method, It occurred to me something like that.

Regards.

Comment: conflicts with id ? just use unique id and it should be fine, I can write you example if you want

Comment: Yeah but should exist a way to do It replacing "ids" to "classes"

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing so would be by using ids. It shouldn't conflict with anything, as long as you do not use the same id twice. Another way would be calling the element by it's class, but then you would have to reference by it's index, like:

```
$.getJSON( "http://api.printoriente.com/price/tarjetas-presentacion", function( data ) {
    $(document).find(".printoriente-label-price")[0].html(data.refPrice);
});
$.getJSON( "http://api.printoriente.com/price/afiches", function( data ) {
    $(document).find(".printoriente-label-price")[1].html(data.refPrice);
});
$.getJSON( "http://api.printoriente.com/price/volantes", function( data ) {
    $(document).find(".printoriente-label-price")[2].html(data.refPrice);
});
$.getJSON( "http://api.printoriente.com/price/Fotos", function( data ) {
    $(document).find(".printoriente-label-price")[3].html(data.refPrice);
});
```